# What is the equivalent resistance between A and B?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, symmetry, electrical-resistance

This question is from a past paper in the Advanced Level Examination of Sri Lanka. Now, I know there are lots of "find the equivalent resistance" questions out there, but I searched everywhere I could but couldn't find a question that matches something like this.

I tried redrawing this but to no avail. Tried to find wheatstone bridges but couldn't find any. This really has me stumped. Please help.

[image: Question]

Comment: This may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform

Answer (score 2):

Here's the circuit with some of the internal nodes labelled:

[image]

As a hint, due to the symmetry of the circuit, all of the nodes I labelled "C" will be at the same potential, and all of the nodes I labelled "D" will be at the same potential.

That means you can connect wires between all the C nodes and between all the D nodes without changing the behavior of the circuit.

After you do that, you will be able to simplify the circuit by making several parallel combinations of resistors, and eventually the equivalent resistance will be easy to find.

You have probably seen a similar trick used to solve a bridge circuit before, so solving this one just requires recognizing you can use the same trick here.

Comment: Yes, symmetry is the key. I found it helpful to move the topmost and bottommost resistors to the left, so that they are directly above and below the batch of 4 resistors, to form a batch of 6. Note that the diagram is a two-dimensional circuit diagram for a classic question: what is the resistance between two furthest-apart vertices of a cubic frame whose members (all 12 of them) each have a resistance $R$ ?

Comment: @PhilipWood the symmetry could be a lot more obvious if you drew the circuit on the side of a cylinder.